# CS50 - Lab 2: Scrabble - Error: called object type 'int [26]' is not a function or function pointer scrabble

Tags: c, cs50

I've been doing this code; supposed to take words from two different players, calculate the score while using the for loop to go through each character one at a time. I've been re-reading it 1000 times, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

I get this error message on lines 45 and 49:

> Error: called object type 'int [26]' is not a function or function pointer scrabble

Don't give me the answer, just give me some kind of guide. Thank you. This is my code:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    //Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    //Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    //Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 is the winner!\n");
    }
    else if (score1 < score2)
    {
        printf("Player 2 is the winner!\n");
    }
    else if (score1 == score2)
    {
        printf("Tie!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    //Compute and return store for string
    int score = 0;
    int l = strlen(word);

    for (int n = 0; n < l; n++)
    {
        if (isupper(word[n]))
        {
            score += POINTS(word[n] - 'A');
        }
        else if (islower(word[n]))
        {
            score += POINTS(word[n] - 'a');
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: CS50 is a C course. Don't tag C++ on C questions.

Comment: Arrays are indexed with square brackets.

Comment: An array is not accessed with curved parentheses as in `POINTS(word[n] - 'A');` but as `POINTS[word[n] - 'A'];` with square brackets. If `POINTS` were a function, it would take the curved parentheses you have used, but it isn't – hence the message.

Comment: The `word[n]` is also an example of array access (each letter within the word). `word[n] - 'A'` ranges it from `0...` and that is used to index the `POINTS` array.

Comment: regarding: `int l = strlen(word); for (int n = 0; n < l; n++)`  that passed in parameter is a NUL terminated array of char (as that is what is returned by: `get_string()`) so this code can be greatly simplified to: `for( int i=0;  word[i]; i++ )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the compiler says, `POINTS` is an array of type `int [26]`. The problematic lines are these:

`POINTS(word[n] - 'A')`

That's just nonsense, you can't use an array like that. The compiler thinks it looks like a function call `()`, hence the strange compiler error. You probably meant to access the array, which would be:

`POINTS[word[n] - 'A']`

But you already knew that, since you got `word[n]` correct...

A tip is to not focus so much on understanding what the compiler error says, as focusing on the line it points at. Compiler messages can be very cryptic and some require a C veteran to understand. For now, just treat them as if the compiler is saying "BAD: line 26".